# Dynamic Pivot table that joins three tables

Tags: php, mysql, pivot

I've used very little php mysql in my time and have to try to relearn some of it for one small project. I have a mysql database with three tables in question here.

USERS TABLE with userID, first name, last name etc.
QUESTION TABLE with questionID, question 
ANSWERS TABLE with userID, questionID, answer

I'm trying to join the three so they are displayed as

```
______   | question | question | question |
jon doe  | answer   | answer   | answer   |
jane doe | answer   | answer   | answer   |
```

and then dynamic so that if a new user is added they will automatically be added to the table. Most of the examples I've been able to find aren't exactly what I'm trying to do, and as I said I barely new enough php mysql to get by a long time ago, and now I'm just trying to get this one thing, but I just can't even wrap my head around where to begin. any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Look into case statements:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)